# is there a way to auto type a list using script writing?

Tags: javascript, ios, list, applescript, keystroke

i need a code which will type each item one after another

for eg: myList {"Apple Watch", "iMac", "iPhone", "MacBook Pro"}

i wanted result typed as:

Apple Watch

iMac

iPhone

MacBook Pro

**i have tried to make a code but cannot do it due to lack of my knowledge**

my code:

```
set theList to {"Apple Watch", "iMac", "iPhone", "MacBook Pro"}
length of theList
tell application "System Events"
    set condition to 0
    set varName to item 1 of theList
    repeat until condition = length of theList
        keystroke of varName
        keystroke return
        set condition to condition + 1
        set varName to (item 1) + condition
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: What application is this typing into ?

Comment: safarii browser

Comment: Ok.  Then there are much better ways of getting your phrases into Safari than simulating keystrokes.

Comment: how? Can you please give me examples?

Comment: Sure, I'll submit an answer to demonstrate in the next few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    tell application "System Events"
        set varX to 1
        set condition to 0
        repeat until condition = length of theList
            set varName to item varX of theList
            keystroke of varName
            delay 0.2
            keystroke return
            set varX to varX + 1
            set condition to condition + 1
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

This script provides the functionality you want. I added the first tell block so that you can run this script as is and see it work within TextEdit, but it will type the text into any application that accepts text input.

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    make new document
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    
    set theList to {"Apple Watch", "iMac", "iPhone", "MacBook Pro"}
    
    repeat with theItem in theList
        set stringLength to the count of theItem
        
        set theString to characters 1 thru stringLength of theItem
        
        repeat with nextCharacter in theString
            keystroke nextCharacter
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        
        keystroke return
        keystroke return
        
    end repeat
    
end tell
```

Comment: wow it really worked

Comment: Why is it keystroking character-by-character?  You can just keystroke the phrase, I.e. `keystroke theItem`.

Comment: I took the description "type each item" to mean simulated typing, but as you point out the script could be easily modified to just keystroke the phrases instead.